# ServiceStack and dynamic properties in request DTOs

Tags: servicestack

I would like to post a JSON object to my service stack service and use a dynamic property in the request DTO. All approaches I have tried so far leave the object being a NULL value.

The javascript code I use:

```
$.getJSON(
  "/api/json/reply/Hello",
  {
    Name: "Murphy",
    Laws: {
      SomeProp: "A list of my laws",
      SomeArr: [
        { Title: "First law" },
        { Title: "Second law" },
        { Title: "Third law" }
      ]
    }   
},
function(data) {
    alert(data.result);
  }
);
```

The DTO to receive the request:

```
public class Hello
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public dynamic Laws { get; set; }
}
```

I also tried to use an object and JsonObject instead of dynamic in the DTO.

To be complete, here's the service too:

```
public class HelloService : Service
{
    public object Any(Hello request)
    {
        return new HelloResponse { Result = "Hello, " + request.Name };
    }
}
```

Murphy comes through in the Name property without any problems, but the Laws property remains NULL.

In the end, I want to somehow iterate (using reflection?) over the Laws property and get all the contained properties and values.

I cannot use a typed DTO here, because I don't know the JSON of the Laws property at development time (and it can change quite frequently).

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The .NET 3.5 library builds of ServiceStack on NuGet doesn't have native support for the .NET 4.0+ **dynamic** type. You can pass JSON into a **string** property and dynamically parse it on the server:

```
public object Any(Hello request)
{
    var laws = JsonObject.Parse(request.Laws);
    laws["SomeProp"] //
    laws.ArrayObjects("SomeArr") //
}
```

Otherwise You can use `Dictionary<string,string>` or if you specify in your AppHost:

```
JsConfig.ConvertObjectTypesIntoStringDictionary = true;
```

You can use `object` which will treat objects like a string dictionary.

Otherwise dynamic shouldn't be on the DTO as it's meaningless as to what the service expects. You could just add it to the QueryString. You can use the [JSV Format](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/wiki/JSV-Format) to specify complex object graphs in the QueryString, e.g:

```
/hello?laws={SomeProp:A list of my laws,SomeArr:[{Title:First Law}]}
```

Note: the spaces above gets encoded with `%20` on the wire.

Which you can access in your services with:

```
public object Any(Hello request)
{
    var laws = base.QueryString["laws"].FromJsv<SomeTypeMatchingJsvSent>();
}
```

Comment: First, thank you very much for your answer. 
When you say "The .NET 3.5 builds..." - does that mean that there are builds somewhere _with_ that functionality?

Comment: Not yet for the entire suite of projects, but there is a .NET 4.0 ServiceStack.Text project with some support for dynamic, Once we offer .NET 4.0 builds we'll look at better support for dynamic across the board.